# Least squares solution when $Ax=B$ actually has a solution

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

I'm searching for an easy proof for this theorem:
(Given $A$ and $b$) If $Ax=b$ has a solution for $x$, then this solution = the least squares solution.

This is how I did it , but I'm not sure everything is correct:

**(Part where I hesitate if it's correct,
*I want to proof $A$ is invertible*)**

let $A$ be a $m \times n$ matrix , $X_0$ the solution vector for $Ax=B$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $B$ a vector in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Because $Ax=B$ has a solution $X_0$, rank of $A = n$.
Since $A$'s rank $= n$ , $A$ is invertible.

**(Part where I'm pretty sure of)**

The least squares solution is given by the formula
$(A^t\cdot A)^{-1}\cdot A^t\cdot B$

Since $A$ is invertible, we can say that $A^t$ is also invertible.
This means we can use the formula $(A^t.A)^{-1} = A^{-1}.(A^t)^{-1}$

The least squares solution then becomes $A^{-1}\cdot(A^t)^{-1}\cdot A^t\cdot B = A^{-1}\cdot B = X_0 $

Comment: How can an $m\times n$ matrix be invertible?

Comment: Don't use $B$ for a vector - it is confusing. Use $b$ instead. ($B$ looks like a matrix...)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2026901/explain-why-x-ab-is-the-shortest-possible-solution-to-ata-hatx-atb

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, if $A$ is not a square matrix, then $A$ isn't invertible, which is the flaw in your proof.

As an alternate route, note that if $Ax = b$ has a solution $x = x_0$, then by definition, $Ax_0 = b$, i.e. $Ax_0 - b = \vec{0}$. Hence, $\|Ax_0-b\|_2 = 0$.

Now, can you show that there are no vectors $x$ such that $\|Ax-b\|_2 < 0$? If you can, then $\|Ax-b\|_2 \ge 0 = \|Ax_0-b\|_2$ for all vectors $x$, and thus, $x = x_0$ is a minimizer of $\|Ax-b\|_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is incorrect, since it assumes that $A$ has an inverse, which may not be the case (even if $A$ is square).

Here's a proof that works:

Suppose that $Ax = b$ has a solution, call this solution $y$.  So, we can rewrite the equation as $Ax = Ay$.  Now, a least squares solution is any $x$ satisfying
$$
A^TAx = A^TA y \implies\\
A^TA(x - y) = 0 \implies\\
(x-y)^TA^TA(x-y) = 0 \implies\\
\|A(x - y)\|^2 = 0 \implies\\
A(x - y) = 0 \implies\\
Ax = Ay
$$
So, every solution to the least squares problem is a solution to the original equation.

Comment: what's the theory behind step 3 to 4 in your equations?

Comment: Note that the dot product of $u$ and $v$ is just $u^Tv$, so that $\|u\|^2 = u^Tu$.

Comment: Okay. Thank you alot :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to carefully look up the statement that you are trying to prove.  Note that the least squares equation
$$\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}A^TA\v x=A^T\v b$$
has a unique solution if and only if $A^TA$ is invertible.  Since you refer to **the** least squares solution and not just **a** least squares solution, I imagine this is the case you want.

It is also known that $A^TA$ is invertible if and only if $A$ has linearly independent columns.  So I think you want the following.

**Theorem**.  Suppose that $A$ has linearly independent columns.  If there is a solution to the system $A\v x=\v b$, then this solution is also the least squares solution.

And in this case the proof is easy: supposing
$$A\v x=\v b\ ,$$
premultiply both sides by $A^T$ to give
$$A^TA\v x=A^T\v b\ ,$$
so that $\v x$ is the least squares solution of the system.

Answer (score 0):

What we know is that $b\in\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right)$, that is, the solution vector is in the column space of $\mathbf{A}$. We are given $\hat{x}$ such that
$$
\mathbf{A} \hat{x} = b.
$$

The least squares minimizers are defined as
$$
  x_{LS} = \left\{ x\in\mathbb{C}^{n} \colon \lVert \mathbf{A} x_{LS} - b \rVert_{2}^{2} \text{ is minimized} \right\}
$$

Because $r^{2}\left( \hat{x} \right) = 0$, $\hat{x}$ is also a least squares minimizer.

**Example**
$$
  \begin{align}
    \mathbf{A} x &= b \\
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x_{1} \\
 x_{2}
\end{array}
\right)
%
 &=
%
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\
 0 \\
 2
\end{array}
\right)
%
  \end{align}
$$
The least squares solutions are
$$
  x_{LS} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 1
\end{array}
\right)
+
\alpha 
\left(
\begin{array}{r}
  1 \\
 -1
\end{array}
\right), \quad \alpha \in \mathcal{C}
$$
Chosing
$$
\hat{x} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \\
 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$
provides a solution which solves the linear system, is a least squares minimizer but is not the solution of minimum norm.

**Addendum**

Given
$$
\mathbf{A}x = b
$$
with
$$
 \mathbf{A}\in\mathcal{C}^{m\times n}, 
  \quad b \in\mathcal{C}^{m}, 
  \quad x \in\mathcal{C}^{n},
$$
The least squares solution is
$$
x_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b + \left( \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A} \right)y, \quad y \in\mathcal{C}^{n}.
$$
For the example
$$
  x_{LS} = 
%
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 1
\end{array}
\right)
%
  +
%
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 1 & -1 \\
 -1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
%
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 y_{1} \\
 y_{2}
\end{array}
\right).
$$